# Tagging image/container with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build an image/container with docker compose. The container builds/runs successfully, but the image `REPOSITORY` and `TAG` both appear as `<none>` in the output for `docker images` and the container gets an auto-generated name (e.g. `eloquent_wiles`). I would for it to tag the image/container with the names specified in my config files (in this case I would like them to be named 'myservice' and the image to be tagged 'v2').

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    build: .
    image: myservice:v2
    container_name: myservice
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
```

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/myservice
COPY . /usr/src/myservice
EXPOSE 1337/tcp
RUN yarn \
  && yarn transpile \
  && node ./build/grpc-server.js
```

`docker -v` gives `Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962`

`docker-compose -v` gives `docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe`

And I am running `docker-compose build`. I get the same results using docker-compose version 2.

I don't suppose anyone can spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That should work. Is there anything else unusual involved here? Are the code snippets truly accurate?

Comment: could it be that the image is there but you don't see it? The images <none>:<none> you mention are intermediary untagged images created by docker. You can clean them with "docker image prune". You can also filter the list of images: docker image ls --filter dangling=false (this will not show the <none>:<none> images)

Comment: @Mihai Thanks for the tip. Yes that image was throwing me off, it turns out the build process wasn't even reaching completion due to my having started the server as part of it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a named image: `docker build -t <repo>:<tag> .` in the directory where the Dockerfile is.
2. Deploy a named service: `docker stack deploy -c <your_yaml_file> <your_stack> --with-registry-auth` in the directory where your YAML is.

Comment: Right. But according to https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/ you should also be able to specify the image name/tag in the config

Comment: Yes, you can. But you have to have the image locally: either you build it or you download it.